# iPhone SQLite encryption with SQLCipher facing errors

Tags: ios4, sqlite, sqlcipher

I am trying to learn about the encryption of DB at application level using [this tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-iphone-sqlite-encryption-with-sqlcipher/). But I am getting an error that says

> sqlcipher/sqlite3.c:11033:25: error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
>   sqlcipher/sqlite3.c:11034:26: error: openssl/rand.h: No such file or directory
>   sqlite3.c:11035:26: error: openssl/hmac.h: No such file or directory

and due these there are around 93 more errors in the build process. I have strictly followed the [tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-iphone-sqlite-encryption-with-sqlcipher/) but I am not able to get rid of those errors.

I have added the path of the source code as instructed in the tutorials but still the problem persists. The screenshot could be seen here

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, in my case it was caused by a space in my OPENSSL_SRC path.  Enclosing the value of OPENSSL_SRC in double-quotes fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages you are seeing indicate that the compiler can't find the OpenSSL headers included in the SQLCipher code. The most likely problem is that you didn't add the OpenSSL headers to your include path when setting up your project. Perhaps you missed this step in the tutorial: "Look for the “Header Search Paths” setting and add references to $(SQLCIPHER_SRC) and $(OPENSSL_SRC). Check “recursive” on both."

As an aside, the information on that MO article is dated. In the future you can refer to this updated tutorial on the SQLCipher website: http://sqlcipher.net/documentation/ios

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but the problems still persists..... i have added the screenshot as well to the question .... can you please suggest any way out of it...... thanks

Answer (score 0):

After long time i'm not sure whether you fixed this issue or not anyway to fix this do as follows:
In OPENSSL_SRC change destination from "/openssl-1.0.0d" to "/openssl-1.0.0d/include".
thatz it..it has to work.